# Example 3.17: find Vo in a circuit containing a voltage controlled voltage source

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, mesh-analysis

Trying to solve this circuit using mesh analysis. However, I am having trouble understanding why Vx = 4kI1 specifically why to go through the 4k resistor using current I1, my intuition wants to set Vx = 4k(I1-I2).

[image: J. David Irwin, Robert M. Nelms - Basic Engineering Circuit Analysis]

Comment: only I1 flows through the 4 k resistor

Comment: My thoughts start with noticing that 2 vx is on one side of the 2k and that vx is on the other side. So i1+i2 = (2 vx-vx)/2k = vx/2k. Since i1=vx/4k, i2 must equal i1. So i2*6k-3=(i1=i2)*4k then i2*2k=3 so i1=i2=3/2k=1.5 mA.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you failed to notice that \$I_2\$ is not indicated for the right-hand loop; rather it applies to elements in the *outer loop* only.

If \$I_2\$ was indicated to flow around the right-hand loop, then both \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ would indeed appear in the expression for the voltage across the 4kΩ resistor, since both \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ flow through it. That's not the case, however. \$I_2\$ is constrained to the outer loop, which *does not include* the 4kΩ resistance.

This means, for instance, that both \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ flow through the 2kΩ resistor, in the same direction, and the voltage across that resistor will therefore be a function of the superposition of both mesh currents:

$$ V_{2k\Omega} = (I_1 + I_2) \times 2k\Omega $$

By contrast, \$I_1\$ flows through the 4kΩ resistor, but \$I_2\$ does not. Therefore \$I_1\$ appears in the expression for voltage across that resistor, but \$I_2\$ does not:

$$ V_{4k\Omega} = I_1 \times 4k\Omega $$